# Contacts LoaderManager and AdapterView OnClick

Tags: java, android

I am trying to attach a basic onClick event to a list of contacts from the device. The list of contacts is generated correctly. A summary of my code is as follows:

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
...
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_view);

        //initialise loader
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACTS_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        mContactsList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //Gets a CursorAdapter
        mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.contacts_list_item,
            null,
            FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
            0);
            //Sets the adapter for the ListView
            mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

       }
     }

        //Followed by all the loader functions

        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {}
        ...
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(this,
            "hello world",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

My onItemClick does not however work. Would I first have to create an instance of OnItemClickListener. I have tried to do this inside the onCreate method and outside and neither work.

Subsequently I have tried the following within my onCreate method

```
   mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "hello world",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you set the clickListener to your list? You probably must do during onCreate: listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: hi, the error I receive then is Class 'Contacts' must be declared as abstract implement method OnitemClick in OnItemClickListener

Comment: If you set the listener as follows "mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()", you should remove "implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener" from your class declaration

Comment: just so i understand, why does one need to remove it from the class declaration when it is set up as "mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()",

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set screen content
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_activity_layout);

        // Find the list view
        ListView mContactsList = findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_LISTVIEW);

        // Set the click listener
        mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "hello world",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Create your adapter and set the adapter to your ListView via mContactsList.setAdapter();
    }
```

Comment: it worked but it did not work... it did not do not nothing when I clicked on the list.. I will post the additional code of my onCreate method